# What might be the cause of noise in my audio out on Stereo when connecting computer as the "audio in"?

Tags: noise

This is from a friend. I wasn't sure of the cause.
Perhaps:

- Ground Loop
- The wire connecting the computer to stereo needs to be shielded?

I have a question about my stereo. I get a hum through my speakers, most pronounced when using an attached computer as a source of Pandora internet radio. I decided the problem was that the receiver wasn't properly grounded. So I got a grounding wire and proceeded to look for an attachment on the back of the receiver. There doesn't seem to be one! It's a Yamaha RX-V663 receiver. Did I mis-diagnose the problem? Is it possible to ground this receiver? How do I find the attachment point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stereo is transformer isolated from AC with a 2 prong plug, while PC is isolated from AC but then chassis is grounded via 3 prong plug. Audio is unbalanced and possibly carrying high common mode noise from PSU.  The ground on the stereo is any chassis screw on the lid, which may help for stray RF but not common-mode conducted hum.  **1) connect ground wire from stereo chassis to PC chassis, wrapped around audio cable. 2) conect high permeability CM choke** around audio cable.  ( Use a clamshell CM choke like those molded on VGA cable.  One of these methods might work. *Also reversing plug on stereo helps on leaky transformers.* ( ac capacitance)